# Отбор уникальных записей, с записью в массив

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день.

Есть табличка, поля: `id, ttl, str` (~100 записей). Как перебрать `ttl`, и отобрать среди них уникальные записи? Можно ли все эти записи записать в массив?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Откровенно говоря мне не понятно за что аж 3 плюса получил запрос

```
  select `ttl` from `table` group by `ttl` order by `id`
```

Вы все в реальных кодах пишите такой бред вместо простого DISTINCT?

2 [[@Ёхарный Бабай](/users/2636/%D1%91%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9)](/users/2636/%D1%91%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9) - нет необходимости добавлять `AS __ttl`, mysql вернет ответ с полями которые и так будут называться `ttl`.

И того:

```
  $dbResult = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT ttl FROM table');

  $ttlData = array(); // массив для заполнения значениями
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbResult)) {
       $ttlData[] = $row; // собственно заполнение
  }
  // в данном случае получим массив вида
  // -> array( array('ttl'=>'...'), array('ttl'=>'...'), array('ttl'=>'...') ... )
  // этот способ описан для того чтобы у вас больше не возникал вопрос о том как
  // сложить выборку БД в массив
```

Если надо получить массив вида

```
  // array('...', '...', '...', ...);
```

Тогда

```
  $ttlData = array(); // массив для заполнения значениями
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbResult)) {
       $ttlData[] = $row['ttl']; // собственно заполнение
  }
  // на выход - массив значений
```

PS: [[@Shrek](/users/4597/shrek)](/users/4597/shrek) это здорово что ты знаешь что DISTINCT выполняет неявный GROUP BY, но писать вместо DISTINCT "group by `field` order by `primaryKey`" бред сивой кобылы.

Comment: Дык, разницы нет особой, я могу в ответ и DISTINCT добавить, не вопрос.

Все по разному пользуются разными функциями.

Comment: Дык разница есть, разница не в производительности а в том что мой запрос понятен и нормален, такой-же как написал ты - бред.

То что ты пишешь читают люди, а в данном случае еще и делать будут так как ты написал (если новички разумееться) т.к. ответ получил много голосов (скорее всего от них же).

Comment: Но не везде же пихать DISTINCT только из -за того что он, как ты говоришь понятен и нормален. Синтаксис твоего и моего запросов, понятен итак, это один и тот же синтаксис MySql. он ни разу не поменяется.

Написал 2 запроса
и не всегда нужно пользоваться именно DISTINCT. от ситуации все равно тоже зависит.

Comment: Так-же можно использовать 

    SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='' OR id='' OR id='' OR id=''

Вместо

    SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN('','','');

И то и то sql, но разница, как по мне, абсолютно очевидна, но вы тут наверно сказали бы - на самом деле `IN('','','')` это тоже самое что и `id='' OR id='' OR id='' OR id=''`, зачем "усложнять" запрос (откровенно говоря тут даже сарказма не получилось т.к. я вообще не понимаю как такое можно было написать в ответе на такой вопрос)

Да и в конкретной задаче очевидно что вариант с `group by .. order by ..` абсолютно излишний

Comment: нет необходимости добавлять AS __ttl

Буду знать...

Comment: Хм) Запрос

    SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1 AND id=2

Никогда не выполнится ;) *шепотом* OR

Comment: Я опечатался. Спасибо, поправил.
PS:авторесайз textarea меня скоро доканает -_-

Comment: А мы сейчас разбираем что круче IN() или перебрать все значения?
Да если человеку вкайф написать 3 раза id='' AND id='' AND id='' AND id='' пусть пишет, если это конечно 3-4, если больше то глупо согласен.
Причем тут акцент на order by ну захотеля так написать, от этого запрос не стал пипец каким сложным, а если новичек, у которого нет ни логики ни мышления, просто копи пастит запросы к БД и радуется - ну это уж, извольте, его судьба, ему пофиг на то займет это 100 символов или 300 символов в запросе, ему главное что работает,

Comment: остальная же часть скорее всего порыскает в инете а что же там такое этот order by и нужен ли он тут.

палка о двух концах.
запросы у меня выполняются одинаково по скорости.

(7,723 total, Query took 0.0007 sec)

(7,723 total, Query took 0.0008 sec)


среднее значение примерно 0.0011 sec

Не вижу разницы, и дискуссия неактуальна. :)

Comment: @Shrek - я просто не вижу смысла усложнять запрос, там где этого можно не делать вот и все
****
По поводу скобок согласен, в данном случае не нужны, поправил ответ

Comment: > SELECT DISTINCT(ttl) FROM table

Скобки не нужны.

Comment: черт, всю жизнь считал, что добавлять в массив, нужно одно значение запихать в массив а потом: foreach ($new_mass as $value) { $massiv[]=$value; } ... понял оба варианта, и попробовал. спасибо всем. жаль пока не хватает рейтинга старить плюсы.

Answer (score 4):

```
$query="select DISTINCT(ttl) FROM `table`" // первый вариант Юзайте этот (говорят он понятнее для Noob)
$query="select `ttl` from `table` group by `ttl` order by  `id`"    // второй вариант
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

собственно ты выберешь все, сгруппируешь их т.е. они будут уникальны ну а потом в php

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array())
{
  echo "Ttl=".$row['ttl']."<br />";
}
```

> DISTINCT, согласно описанию, **выполняет неявный GROUP BY**. **Отличие в
> производительности может быть**, но объяснить его рационально сложно.
> Индексы использует, но нужны правильные составные индексы, так как
> GROUP BY выполняется после WHERE.

Время выполнения запроса

```
(7,723 total, Query took 0.0007 sec)// DISTINCT
(7,723 total, Query took 0.0008 sec)// group by
среднее значение примерно 0.0011 sec
```

Comment: потрясающе, но вот только я не хотел им делать "echo", я хотел массив с уникальными записями, а уже потом чудить с ними 8-)

Comment: так обрабатывай его как хочешь, я просто пример вывода написал.
ощущение что я просто навязываю юзать свой код и только так как написал его автор, без права редактирования :)

Comment: Вот собственно и все.
Как бы дискуссия на тему что у меня плохо выиграла. Не мне не обидно, просто у автора вопроса в голове бардак, первый раз встречаю что ответ был принят а потом был отдан другому.

Повторюсь мне не обидно. даже могу и ответ удалить

Comment: @Shrek - это к чему написано? О_о

Comment: к тому самому.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ttl) AS _ttl FROM `table` ORDER BY _ttl
```